# Not able to call @future from @future

Tags: apex, visualforce, future, httprequest

I am trying to call `@future` method from  trigger and got `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY` Error, because of update operation within the `@future` method. Class and triggers given below.

**Error Message**

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003o0000019gMu6AAE; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, xrx_mf_crm.RepWebserviceCall: execution of AfterUpdate
>
> caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future o.

**Class**

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void AuthCallout(Set<Id> contactIds) {

    List<Contact> ContactUpdate = [SELECT id  FROM Contact where Id IN :contactIds];
    String ContactID;

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setTimeout(60000); 
    req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); // Content Type
    req.setMethod('GET'); 

    for (Contact c : ContactUpdate)
    {    
        ContactID = c.id;

        req.setEndpoint('https://xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/xxx-lookup?ContactID=' + ContactID);

        Http http = new Http();

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

        String GMMID;
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'GCGMM')) {
                // Get the value.
                parser.nextToken();
                // Compute the grand total price for all invoices.
                GMMID = parser.gettext();
            }
        }
        
        //ContactUpdate.IsFutureContext__c = true;
        C.Group_ID__c = GMMID;
        update c;
    }
}
```

## Trigger:

```
trigger ContactWebserviceCall on Contact (After insert) {
    for (Contact co : Trigger.new)
    {
        If(co.Rep_ID__c.substring(0,3) == 'CRM')
        {
            ContactWebServiceCall. AuthCallout (Trigger.newMap.keySet());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provide the entire text of the error message **verbatim**. That aside, I don't see an `@future` method anywhere in your provided code. If your `AuthCallout` method is the one with the `@future` annotation, you'll also need to specify `callout=true`. Calling a future method inside of a loop is also a bad idea (the governor limit for @future calls is 50 per transaction).

Comment: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003o0000019gMu6AAE; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, xrx_mf_crm.ContactWebserviceCall: execution of AfterUpdate

Comment: The callout happens only when the record meets certain criteria. that's the reason for not worrying about governors limit. But am reading @future method, we cannot perform update to any record. is that true?

Comment: It still feels like you're not including the entire error message (also, please [edit] your question to include that, rather than putting it in the comments). Regarding callouts, there's some confusion in terminology here. An `@future` callout is simply calling an `@future` annotated method. Those are limited to 50 per transaction, and if you have more than 50 `Contacts` being inserted together you're risking going over that limit. In other words, your trigger is not properly bulkified.

Comment: @DerekF I added the entire error message i got from debug log. Yes you are correct on governors limit. But my main issue is updating the contact record, if that happens, i will be able to manage the limit issue later.

Comment: Ok, I see that you added the entire error message, and that tells me exactly what the issue is. I'll start writing up an answer, and give you an upvote on the question for working with me to add important details to your question (instead of abandoning your question for hours or days like I see all too often).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're having isn't that you can't call an `@future` method from a trigger, but rather that you end up trying to call an `@future` method when you're already in an `@future` context.

It isn't happening because of your trigger, but somehow, running a DML `update` on your `Contacts` in your `@future` method is causing your `@future` method (or perhaps some other `@future` method) to be called again. It can't be because of the trigger that you've provided because that trigger only runs `After Insert` (not on an update).

The likely solution here is to add some extra code that exercises some extra caution when handling `@future` calls.

The basic example of the pattern I'm talking about is this

```
public class SaferFutureCall{
    // In this method, which you'll note is not given the @future annotation, you'll
    //   place the code that you have in your current, not-as-safe, @future method
    private static void doNormal(List<Id> idList){
        List<Contact> ContactUpdate = [SELECT id  FROM Contact where Id IN :idList];
        String ContactID;

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setTimeout(60000); 
        req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); // Content Type
        req.setMethod('GET');

        // ...and the rest of your current code
    }

    // This method doesn't look like it does too much, it's all we need to do to
    //   execute the 'doNormal' method above in an @future context.
    @future(callout=true)
    private static void doFuture(List<Id> idList){
        workToDo(idList);
    }

    // This is where the magic happens
    public static void execute(List<Id> idList){
        if(System.isFuture() || System.isBatch()){
            // If we're in an async context that doesn't allow @future callouts,
            //   we can just simply call the non-@future version of the method.
            // This avoids the "can't call @future from @future" error.
            doNormal(idList);
        } else {
            // If we're not in an async context, we can call the @future version
            //   (provided you haven't hit the limit yet)
            if(Limits.getFutureCalls() < Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()){
                doFuture(idList);
            } else {
                // place some code in here to explicitly notify you that your request
                //   to run an @future method was denied.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this class is pretty straightforward, you'd replace your direct call to the `@future` method with

SaferFurure.execute(someIdList);

With that out of the way, we can turn attention to removing the `@future` call from inside a loop.

Given your provided trigger, it appears that you might not want to call your `@future` method with every record being inserted. I also doubt that you want to be repeatedly calling your `@future` method with the same data multiple times (which is a very likely possibility with the trigger that you currently have).

Instead, making your trigger bulk-friendly would involve first preparing the data that you want to send to your `@future` method, and, in a separate section of trigger code, then calling your `@future` method.

An example based on your provided trigger:

```
trigger ContactWebserviceCall on Contact (After insert) {
    // First, initialize a collection to hold data that you'll be gathering
    Set<Id> contactIdsForCallout = new Set<Id>();

    // Loop over your trigger context variable to gather your target data
    for (Contact co : Trigger.new){
        if(co.Rep_ID__c.substring(0,3) == 'CRM'){
            contactIdsForCallout.add(co.Id);
        }
    }

    // And then pass data (once, and only once) to your callout method.
    // In keeping with my example code, and your trigger code, you have a set
    //   but SaferFuture.execute() requires a List.
    // Creating a new list, and passing the set in to the constructor can easily
    //   take care of this for us.
    SaferFurure.execute(new List<Id>(contactIdsForCallout));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Derek. Your solution resolved both callout and governors limit problems.